# Make postfix retry PNCR Status (5xy code)

Tags: linux, postfix

Every now and then I am forced to send medium volumes (100-1000 mails) to microsoft smtp servers (outlook.com/hotmail.com)

```
outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com
Remote Server returned '554 5.7.1 <outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com #5.7.1 smtp; 550 5.7.1 Unfortunately, messages from [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list (S3150). You can also refer your provider to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. [XXXX.eop-eur05.prod.protection.outlook.com 2023-09-06TXX:XX:XX.XXXXZ XXXX]>'
```

Microsoft Blocklist `S3150` referes to an *temporary* rate-limiting List you might land on when you're sending too many mails in a given time.
apparently changing the mail-generating application is nothing i can do.

By returning a Permanent Negative Completion Reply postfix does not retry sending that mail. (which I totally understand)

however my ip usally gets whitelisted automatically within up to 12 hours and I am free to send again.

is there any option in postfix to keep mails with pncr replies in the queue?